# Guardar consulta en php

Tags: php

Deseo que mi consulta se guarde en php de esta manera

```
 var data = [
            {nameusuario:IT01, dia:15, mes:9, axo:2017, IDsemana:1, cara:0},
            {nameusuario:IT01, dia:22, mes:9, axo:2017, IDsemana:2, cara:0},
            {nameusuario:IT01, dia:29, mes:9, axo:2017, IDsemana:3, cara:0},
            {nameusuario:IT01, dia:06, mes:10, axo:2017, IDsemana:4, cara:3},
            {nameusuario:IT01, dia:13, mes:10, axo:2017, IDsemana:5, cara:4},
            {nameusuario:IT03, dia:15, mes:9, axo:2017, IDsemana:1, cara:3},
            {nameusuario:IT01, dia:22, mes:9, axo:2017, IDsemana:2, cara:4}
           ]
```

asi sucesivamente, que puedo usar para que se guarde así? he intentado con assoc y array pero se guardan así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitarás usar la función de [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) que te permitirá codificar el array a JSON.

```
$data = array(
          array(
             'nameusuario' => 'IT01',
             'dia' => '15',
             'mes' => '10',
             'axo' => '2017',
             'IDsemana' => '5',
             'cara' => '0'
       )
);

$json = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me ayudo mucho tu comentario, es lo que nesecitaba